# Getting aggregated value using ElasticsearchTemplate and aggregators

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am having problems extracting the aggregated value.

configuration is spring with spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch.

Document user indexed multiples times in database.

I want to return sum of fields 'commentsCnt'

```
@Autowired
ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate;

SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
    .withIndices("comment")             
    .withQuery(matchQuery("user", userName))       
    .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.sum("sum_of_comments").field("commentsCnt"))
    .build();

Aggregations aggregations = elasticsearchTemplate.query(searchQuery, 
        new ResultsExtractor<Aggregations>() {
            @Override
            public Aggregations extract(SearchResponse response) {
                return response.getAggregations();
        }
});

Aggregation ret = aggregations.get("sum_of_comments");
```

How to extract the value? Maybe there is a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    for (Aggregation aggs : aggregations) {

         Sum sum = (Sum) aggs;
         double sumValue = sum.getValue();
          System.out.println("sumValue=" + sumValue);
  }
```